# ¿como convertir de ISO-8859-1 a UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8

necesito convertir mi archivo html que esta en charset=iso-8859-1 a UTF-8, me podrian ayudar?

este es mi código:

```
 string converHtml = File.ReadAllText(html);
      
 Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");

 Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
 byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(converHtml);

 byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, isoBytes);

 string msg = utf8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

            
 msg = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(msg);

 return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

lo pude resolver con estas lineas de código:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(html, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));

 var ags = sr.ReadToEnd();
```